# Can we get rid of the frameworks tag?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The [frameworks](/questions/tagged/frameworks) tag has 6k+ questions relating to .net, xcode, php, Java, android, and more. The questions tagged by it aren't exactly related, except that they all use a framework. Most of the questions either are also tagged with a specific, relevant framework (e.g. [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) or [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework)), and the ones that aren't are typically off-topic (e.g. asking for advice in choosing a framework).

Can we get rid of it?

Comment: It will be a useful tag for questions about how to design/implement frameworks; however I can’t see how to stop it being used for every specific framework that is out there.

Comment: @IanRingrose:  I can't see how "how to implement/design a framework" would be on-topic for SO, though.

Comment: @IanRingrose Broad questions about framework implementation are off-topic, and questions about specific problems encountered during framework implementation/design would be better tagged regarding the specific problem, not the overarching umbrella of frameworks in general.

Comment: Frameworks have different design tradeoffs as the users of a framework expect to be able to extent and adopted it without refactoring its source code.     Also the framework cannot be change in any way that breaks a user’s code, but the framework writers do not have access to the user’s code or tests.

Comment: @IanRingrose In cases about choosing the right framework (though I'm not sure how these would be on topic) there are tags like [tag:web-frameworks] and [tag:javascript-framework], which give a more specific categorization. I can't think of a case where an on-topic question would relate to *all* types of frameworks. It's too broad.

Answer (score 3):

It probably shouldn't be used on questions that can use a specific framework tag, but it appears that there are quite a few questions it's on that don't have/aren't using that option.